# AngularJS $resource error while using ODataAngularResources

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use ODataAngularResources. I read the documentation and did exactly the way it's shown [here](https://github.com/devnixs/ODataAngularResources). Here's how I'm using it.

```
$scope.claims = $odataresource("/odata/DeniedClaims")
                    .odata().withInlineCount().take(20).query();
```

The `Network` in Chrome dev shows the data, but I still get the following error:

```
Error: [$resource:badcfg] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$resource/badcfg?p0=Error%20in%20resource…4=GET&p5=%2Fodata%2FDeniedClaims%3F%24top%3D20%26%24inlinecount%3Dallpages
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I resolve this? The data is being sent from the server as JSON. When I enter the `http://localhost/odata/DeniedClaims` in the browser, I get all data as json array.

Comment: The link in your error message tells you why: "This error occurs when the $resource service expects a response that can be deserialized as an array but receives an object, or vice versa. By default, all resource actions expect objects, except query which expects arrays."

Comment: Right. I read that one too in the documentation, but I couldn't tell why I'm getting that error from the code. There's nothing else in my code other than the one that I showed to retrieve the data. It's only getting the data from the server using ODataAngularResources. How can I deserialize as an array? I thought all I needed to do is was retrieve the data from the server. The server is sending in json.

Comment: The format that I'm receiving it in (as shown in Chrome Network tab) is like this: `odata.metadata: "http://localhost:58891/odata/$metadata#DeniedClaims",…}
odata.metadata: "http://localhost:58891/odata/$metadata#DeniedClaims"
value: [{id: 14, AuthID: "1111223223", Status: "DENIED", EffectiveDate: "2015-08-10T00:00:00",…},…]`

Comment: I'm confused. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must've been using old version of OData in .Net. I uninstalled and re-installed OData, and set the reference to `using System.Web.OData` instead of `using System.Web.Http.OData`. I also changed the routing config from `config.Routes.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata", GetEdmModel())` to `config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata","odata",GetEdmModel())`. Then, I just had to remove `withInlineCount()` from the AngularJS controller. This worked for me. I'm still not sure why the previous one would cause error in `$resource`.